# apache shows the content of my public dir - rails + apache + passenger + local git + capistrano + ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, capistrano

I decided just recently to implement my RoR project in a production experimental environment.
The problem I'm experiencing is when trying to view my main app page, apache would show the content of public directory instead.

### Important notes:

1. I have deleted the index.html file from public (before, apache would show the rails welcome page)
2. I have a map root route in my route.rb - that used to perfectly work in my dev envronment.

   map.root :controller => 'home'
3. I'm using the virtual host file that was automatically created by capistrano deployment under
   /etc/apache2/sites-available/appname

   its Content:

   NameVirtualHost specific.ip.address:80

   ServerName specific.ip.address

   DocumentRoot /var/www/appname/current/public

### Dev environment (in which everything works fine):

Ruby and Rails installed on my macbook pro using the default mongrel configuration

### Experimental production environment (where I'm experiencing the problem):

1. Ubuntu 9.04 32 bit
2. Rails, Ruby, Apache, git (local), passenger and capistrano were installed and configured following the instructions in :
   http://hackd.thrivesmarthq.com/how-to-setup-a-linux-server-for-ruby-on-rails-with-github-and-phusion-passenger
3. all steps went fine including the capistrano deployment which successfully deployed my app under:
   /var/www/appname/current/
4. as detailed above, when trying to view my main app page - apache would show the content of my public dir (even though I don't have index.html and I have a map root route that worked in dev)

Regards,
Jason

Comment: In addition, when I'm trying to navigate directly to my home view using:
"http://ip_address/home"
"http://ip_address/home/index"
"http://ip_address/appname/home"
"http://ip_address/appname/home/index"

I'm getting the Error 404 page.

Comment: Did you restart apache? Also check out http://articles.slicehost.com/. Their tutorials cover pretty much everything and are very well done.

Comment: It seems like the request is not being handled by Passenger. When you copied the LoadModule text did you start a new line before RailsSpawnServer and RailsRuby? What version of Passenger are you using because that syntax is different than what I used for version 3.

Comment: Thanks for you comments.
Mark, I did restart my apache.
Brian, I think the request is handled by passenger, check out the error 404 page I'm getting is served by passenger (when specifying home/index) "Not Found

The requested URL /appname/home was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/2.0.3 Server at ip_address Port 80"

Answer (score 3):

add

```
Options -Indexes
```

to a directory configuration settings in your virtualhost. Either in

```
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes 
</Directory>
```

or in your document root

```
<Directory /var/www/appname/current/public>
    Options -Indexes 
</Directory>
```

Comment: I added the first option, and it changed something.
Now, the page just keep reloading and never finishes.
I checked in /var/log/apache2/error.log and found the following error:
[Thu Jan 06 09:19:42 2011] [error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: The Passenger spawn server script, '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/lib/passenger/passenger-spawn-server', does not exist. Please check whether the 'PassengerRoot' option is specified correctly.
Any idea? 
-Jason

Comment: I just realized that there's no directory named "passenger" under lib but instead there's "phusion_passenger"

Comment: You'll need a rails expert maybe, I was able to prevent directory listing from apache, now it's a different problem.